# Swiping to next page in uiautomator

Tags: android, testing, android-uiautomator

How do i swipe to next page in uiautomator apps screen.

I have tried

```
d.swipe(531,1346,1033,1346,20)
```

i have changed the `last parameter to 20 or 200` or any number and it does not seem to swipe to the next page.

[image]

Comment: what's the resolution of your device?

Comment: @PageNotFound 1080 x 1920 xxhdpi

Comment: Did you try `d.swipe(1033,1346,531,1346,200)`?

Comment: @PageNotFound It worked. Can you add it as an answer so i could accept and upvote it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to swipe from Right to Left instead of Left to Right.

```
d.swipe(1033,1346,531,1346,20) #steps taken will determine the speed
```